# Crystal Report Selection Formula

Tags: vb.net-2010

Good Morning! As i was developing my software (School Management) using VS 2010 and SSMS without any problem, until i reached the final stage where i want use a crystal report to print a Student Report. in my software i used Table Adapter to generate the student on datagridview before attempting to print. using

```
[Me.Assessment1TableAdapter.FillBySession(Me.EMS.Assessment1, cboRSession.Text, cboRClass.Text, cboRTerm.Text, cboeReg.Text]
```

where i will select Secion, Class, Term, Reg. before i generate the Students List. so Please what is the best way for me to create a Crystal Report because i want add some tables in it for Teacher's comment and i am very new to Crystal Report. Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that explains the problem you're having or question you're asking. *Visual Basic* is clear by the tag you used, and removing it leaves *Crystal Report*. How does that give any meaning to a future reader who sees it in a search result when trying to solve a problem? Your title should be descriptive and clear, not a jumble of tag information and meaningless content. Also, we're not a tutorial site; we're not going to teach you how to use Crystal Reports here. Use the documentation, and use Google to search for tutorials or lessons or blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem by using Selection Formula which is :

```
    REPORT_SHEET.CrvReport.Enabled = True
    REPORT_SHEET.CrvReport.ReportSource = "C:\Users\MUSTAPHA YUSUF\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SMS\SMS\Student_CrystalReport.rpt"
    REPORT_SHEET.CrvReport.SelectionFormula = "{Assessment.ID}=" + Sol.Text
    REPORT_SHEET.CrvReport.Refresh()
    REPORT_SHEET.CrvReport.RefreshReport()
    REPORT_SHEET.Show()
```